# AWS EC2 Export Instance Task Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, export

I am exporting an EC2 Instance to a VM by following steps give here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html

Under Monitor an instance export task, the Status shows as "Active" since about 6 hours now. Data is around 160GB on instance.

```
{
    "ExportTasks": [
        {
            "ExportTaskId": "export-i-<ID>",
            "ExportToS3Task": {
                "ContainerFormat": "ova",
                "DiskImageFormat": "vmdk",
                "S3Bucket": "exportedvmec2",
                "S3Key": "export-i-<ID>.ova"
            },
            "InstanceExportDetails": {},
            "State": "active"
        }
    ]
}
```

How long it takes for this to complete? Also, how do we make sure that this has not gone "Frozen"?

Comment: Came here while googling for the same question . Did your export task ever finish successfully?

Comment: Addition: After approx. 3 hours, my (rather small) machine was exported successfully with state "completed".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not much information about it.. In my case I had a 500GB vm, and it took almost 18 hours.

Comment: so a vm of almost 1 tb could take approx 36 hours???